# Darkflow accurate on demo but not on code

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, yolo, darkflow

I trained my own model with darkflow yolov2 for just one class, and the results are pretty good when running this on the terminal with a threshold configuration of 0.55

```
python3 flow --model cfg/yolov2-tiny-voc-1c.cfg --load 5250 --demo BARCELONA_WALK.mp4
```

but then I convert the checkpoint on pb and meta files to use on code
and when I specify the threshold on the code like this

```
options = {"model": "cfg/yolov2-tiny-voc-1c.cfg", 
        "pbload": "built_graph/yolov2-tiny-voc-1c.pb",
        "metaload": "built_graph/yolov2-tiny-voc-1c.meta",
        "threshold": 0.55,
        "gpu": 0.9}
```

it detects nothing from my image samples, but when the threshold is 0.5 or lower it detects like 280 objects and the ones with confidence greater than 0.5 are like 190, so, why is the neural network not working the same way when using the code and when running demo from terminal if I'm using the same weights and the same threshold?

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED!!! On my options I had to put "pbLoad" and "metaLoad" instead of "pbload" and "metaload" too bad that it didn't throw any errors but anyways, I realized it may be the Uppercases when reading this post. I hope it helps someone in the future!!